# Javascript: binding lenght in a class

Tags: javascript, class

I solved this exercise from a book, but I have questions (below).

> Write a class Vec that represents a vector in two-dimensional space. It takes x and y parameters (numbers), which it should save to properties of the same name.
>
> Give the Vec prototype two methods, plus and minus, that take another vector as a parameter and return a new vector that has the sum or difference of the two vectors’ (this and the parameter) x and y values.
>
> Add a getter property length to the prototype that computes the length of the vector—that is, the distance of the point (x, y) from the origin (0, 0).

Then the exercise gives an example of what the results should be:

```
// Your code here.

console.log(new Vec(1, 2).plus(new Vec(2, 3)));
// → Vec{x: 3, y: 5}
console.log(new Vec(1, 2).minus(new Vec(2, 3)));
// → Vec{x: -1, y: -1}
console.log(new Vec(3, 4).length);
// → 5
```

I solved the exercise as follows:

```
class Vec {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        length = Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
        }
    plus(v) {
        return { x: this.x + v.x, y: this.y + v.y };
    }
    minus(v) {
        return { x: this.x - v.x, y: this.y - v.y };
    }

}

console.log(new Vec(1, 2).plus(new Vec(2, 3)));
// → Vec{x: 3, y: 5}
console.log(new Vec(1, 2).minus(new Vec(2, 3)));
// → Vec{x: -1, y: -1}
console.log(new Vec(3, 4).length);
// → 5
```

This works but I'd like to improve my solution. If I change the values of x or y of my vector, the length value will be wrong since it's calculated in the constructor. Example:

```
let vecTest = new Vec(3, 4);

console.log(vecTest.length);
// → 5 (this value is ok)

vecTest.x -= 3;
// the value of x has now changed, but the lenght value has not!

console.log(vecTest.length);
// → 5 (this value is NOT ok)

console.log(Math.sqrt(vecTest.x * vecTest.x + vecTest.y * vecTest.y));
// → 4 (this is what the value should be)
```

I know I could use a function to achieve this, but is there a way to do it just using a binding? I tried to use the prototype like this:

```
Vec.prototype.length = Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
```

I set this value outside of the class, but it doesn't work. "this" is in fact undefined.

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for the `.length` property:

```
class Vec {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x || 0;
        this.y = y || 0;
    }
    get length() {
      return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
    }
    // ...
}
```

The `.length` property of instances becomes a dynamically computed value.

You may also want to make the `.plus` and `.minus` functions chainable instead of returning object literals.

```
plus(v) {
    this.x += v.x
    this.y += v.y;
    return this;
}
minus(v) {
    this.x -= v.x
    this.y -= v.y;
    return this;
}
```

Now you can code `new Vec(...).plus(...).plus(...).minus(...).length`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Vec {
  constructor(a,b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
  plus(c){
    return `Vec{x : ${this.a + this.b}, y : ${c.a + c.b} }`;
  }
  minus(c){
    return `Vec{x : ${this.a - this.b}, y : ${c.a - c.b} }`;
  }
  length(){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.a,2) + Math.pow(this.b,2));
  } 
}


console.log(new Vec(1, 2).plus(new Vec(2, 3)));
// → Vec{x: 3, y: 5}
console.log(new Vec(1, 2).minus(new Vec(2, 3)));
// → Vec{x: -1, y: -1}
console.log(new Vec(3, 4).length());
// → 5`
```